# How to Reverse Dropdown Box - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

I have a form on my website that users fill out their name, and all their information. When they submit the form, the data goes to a google spreadsheet.

I then have another sheet that has a dropdown box that auto-populates the names (and ID #) from the first sheet. If you click the dropdown box, it lists all the names. When you select a name, the rest of the sheet populates with their info.

This initially worked great, however as I am getting hundreds (maybe thousands) of submissions, my dropdown is getting lots of names and every time I go to select a name, I have to scroll to the bottom of the dropdown to get the recent submissions. I normally only need to access the most recent submissions.

I see potentially three ways of handling this but I do not know how to do any of these:

1. Can I reverse the dropdown data so that it pulls the most recent names from the original data sheet first. OR
2. Another way of doing this is to make so that when someone submits a new submissions, that it adds the new line to the top of the data sheet, not at the bottom. OR
3. I have an ID # with each name (in a different Column). Can I sort the dropdown box by alphabetical order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use either option 1 or 3

For this you should **create a helper column** using

**Option 1**: **Reverse the dropdown data** so that it pulls the most recent names from the original data sheet first.

`=SORT(G3:G18,ROW(G3:G18)*N(G3:G18<>""),0)`

**Option 3**: Sort the dropdown box by **alphabetical order**

```
`=SORT(G3:G18)`
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

You can then **use the helper column as your drop-down range**

Comment: I think that is the right track, however I am struggling to create the helper column. Could you post the formula in "H3" and "H4" in your example spreadsheet you posted?

Comment: @Ben I already posted both of them. They are the ones to use. If still having issues please create a test sheet, give it editing permissions and let us know of it's link.

Comment: I think I figured it out. When I input your formula in, it did not delete the empty cells (like it did in your example). However the Dropdown Box disregards empty cells, so its no big deal. Thankyou!

Comment: *"When I input your formula in, it did not delete the empty cells"*. You probably do not have any empty cells since the range is the result of a form. In any case, glad you worked it out.